# how can i run an abstract method in Python (child will implement it) and abstract hirrachy

Tags: python, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am complete new to Python , and i want to convert a Java project to Python, this is a a basic sample of my code in Java: (i truly want to know how to work with abstract classes and polymorphism in Python)

```
public abstract class AbstractGrandFather {

   protected ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

   protected AbstractGrandFather(){
          list.add(getGrandFatherName());
   }

   protected abstract String getGrandFatherName();

}

public abstract class AbstractParent extends AbstractGrandfather {

   protected AbstractParent(String name){
          super();
          list.add(name);
}

public class Child extends AbstractParent {

   public Child(String fatherName, String childName){
          super(fatherName);
          list.add(childName);
   }

   public String getGrandFatherName(){
          return "Samuel";
   }
}
```

This is what i tried to do in Python:

```
import abc
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractGrandFather(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        list = [self.get_command_name(self)]

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_command_name(self):
        pass

    @property
    def get_list(self):
        return self.list

class AbstractParent(AbstractGrandFather):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.list = super.get_list.append(name)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_command_name(self):
        pass

class Child(AbstractParent):
    def get_command_name(self):
        return "Samuel"

    def __init__(self, father_name, child_name):
        self.list = super(father_name).get_list.append(child_name)


x = Child("Dan," "Ben")
```

but it doesn't work and i get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dummy.py", line 43, in <module>
    x = Child("Dan," "Ben")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Am I on the right track ? will appreciate some help and guiding lines.

Thank you

Comment: First, `super` doesn't work the exact same way in Python (among other things, because Python supports multiple inheritance). Also, we'd need to know the version of Python you're targetting, because Python 3 introduces some changes in `super`. Third... oh my... getters in Python. *shudder*

Comment: Im working on PyCharm, and the interpreter is Python 2.7.2

and the getter is only cause i don't know how to get to the "Grandfather" field "list" otherwise (for appending)
 will glad for a better solution..

Comment: Fix your line: `x = Child("Dan", "Ben")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: fixed for multipython compatibility
Edit2: added some pointers at the end...

Have a look at this:

```
class AbstractGrandFather(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = [self.get_command_name()]

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_command_name(self):
        pass

    @property
    def list(self):
        return self._list


class AbstractParent(AbstractGrandFather):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(AbstractParent, self).__init__()
        self.list.append(name)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_command_name(self):
        pass


class Child(AbstractParent):
    def get_command_name(self):
        return "Samuel"

    def __init__(self, father_name, child_name):
        super(Child, self).__init__(father_name)
        self.list.append(child_name)
```

On Python 3 it's `super()` is enough, no need for `super(class, instance)`.

You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) about `super`.

Comment: it still gives me:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dummy.py", line 43, in <module>
    x = Child("Dan," "Ben")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Im working on PyCharm, and the interpreter is Python 2.7.2

Comment: Works for me as is, with Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2

Comment: it was my bad , needed to change: 
x = Child("Dan", "Ben") 

You are the Best !

Comment: It was a bit unlucky on your side. Python `"..." "..."` works the same as `"..." + "..."`, so you were getting a totally unrelated error.